# How to get size of an array through pointer?

Tags: c++

If I try to get the size of an array,
I get the size of an array,
but if I try to get it through a pointer, it doesn't work

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[10];

    cout << sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) << endl; // works

    int *p = a;

    cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]) << endl; // doesn`t work
}
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: You can't. This is why [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) exists.

Comment: Forget C-style arrays exist. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` always.

Comment: More generally, if you want a function to accept a sequence of elements you should accept a pair of iterators (`template <typename It> void foo(It begin, It end)`) and then your function can work with any array or container (that has iterators compatible with your algorithm). The size of the sequence would just be `end - begin`.

Comment: `constexpr size_t a_size = 10; int a[a_size];` And you're golden.  Just use `a_size` when you want to know the size of `a`.